# Handy tool to grab images from a flash designed website?

Tags: gratis, windows-7, flash

I wasn't sure on how exactly to title my question but is there a program that can grab images off of a fully flashed kind of website like this [here](http://www.d3p.co.jp/stormlover_natsukoi/). My goal is to somehow be able to individually grab all of the images or the background etc in the flash content but don't know how to do it.

Some requirements are...

- Free (Gratis)
- Runs on Windows 7
- Lightweight
- Requires no admin permission to run

Any ideas/suggestions

Answer (score 1):

One way, though it might not work if the code is obfuscated or some images need to be retrieved from Internet on the fly:

Step 1: Download the Flash Files by looking at the [page source](http://www.wikihow.com/Download-SWF-Files) (e.g. in your case http://www.d3p.co.jp/stormlover_natsukoi/preloader.swf)

Step 2: Use some Flash Decompiler Tool to extract images from it, such as:

- [SWFTools](http://www.swftools.org/about.html): free, Windows/Linux, CLI: `swfextract preloader.swf` to list of resources:

The result is something [like](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=966877):

```
Objects in file myfile.swf:
[-i] 3 Shapes: ID(s) 1-3
[-i] 5 MovieClips: ID(s) 4, 5, 8, 10, 12
[-j] 3 JPEGs: ID(s) 69, 116, 447
[-p] 1 PNG: ID(s) 318
[-s] 3 Sounds: ID(s) 28-30
[-f] 10 Frames: ID(s) 0-10
```

Now you can extract a shape using

```
swfextract -i 2 preloader.swf -o shape.swf
```

a sound (actually there is none in this file) using

```
swfextract -s 28 preloader.swf -o sound.wav
```

a PNG image file using

```
swfextract -p 1 preloader.swf -o file.png
```

- [JPEXS Free Flash Decompiler](http://www.free-decompiler.com/flash/) (free, open source, works with Java on Windows, Linux or MacOS.):

[image]

- [Sothink SWF Decompiler](http://www.sothink.com/page/swf-decompiler/extract-images-from-flash.htm): (non-free, Windows):

[image]

(I forgot which decompiler I used to blow the 200-file upload limit on late [Wixi](http://www.crunchbase.com/organization/wixi), which was hardcoded in the Flash client code).